# Cannot connect ORACLE ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor in XAMPP

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, sqlplus

I have an SQL Plus Instance 19.3 which is connected through OCI8 to my php webserver in xampp,

previously I had this all working where the webpage would display the content of the database, having come back to my computer after a holiday, and edited nothing I now get the error "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" and I am not sure how to fix it as I'm not sure what has changed?.

my username/password are correct, the database name is correct.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Load Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Customer Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>SHOW CUSTOMER DATA</h2>

    <?php
        //Connect to Oracle database
        $conn = oci_connect('ali', 'abc123', '//localhost/orcl');
        
        

        if (!$conn) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        } 

        $query = "SELECT table_name FROM USER_TABLES";
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
        oci_execute($stid);

        echo '<ul>';

        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
            echo '<li>' . $row['TABLE_NAME'] . '</li>';
            
        }

        oci_close($conn);
    ?>
    
</body>
```

is the webpage I use just as a simple connection test. trying to follow other threads has yieled no luck, and I fear i'll be changing too many things and end up in a spiraled nest of half attempt at fixes.

alot of pages mention tnsnames.ora and listener.ora so here they are respectively

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Users\aliba\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

and

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Users\aliba\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\aliba\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\aliba\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: First `sqlplus` is not a database: it is a client, command-line tool. Second, is your database instance actually up and running? This error would suggest that it may not be.

Comment: Did you try using the ['Easy Connect'](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-21c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf) syntax?   This doesn't need tnsnames.ora or sqlnet.ora files.  For PHP examples, look on page 104 of the free [Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html)